# Move cursor on scrollWheel:(NSEvent *)event

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos

I'm using `- (void)scrollWheel:(NSEvent *)event;` to move around a `NSView` inside a `NSViewController`. Moving and detecting the scrollWheel Event works just fine - however the cursor on the screen stays at it's inital position once the scroll event begins (I guess it's the intended behaviour). Is there a possibility to move the cursor based on the scroll movement?

Comment: Will the user expect this behaviour?

Comment: Thank you - I wonder why this question didn't pop up when I started the thread. That actually solved my problem. I use scrollingDeltaX and scrollingDeltaX on the event and set the mouse cursor programmatically with CGDisplayMoveCursorToPoint